# Properties of the monad for the LieAlgebra adjunction

Tags: category-theory, quantum-mechanics

The Lie Algebra is indeed an algebra for a monad.  We see [some background here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870143/for-which-category-if-any-are-lie-algebras-the-algebras-of-a-monad).  As such, the category of Lie Algebras has an adjunction into Set.  This means that there is a monad, $(L,\mu, \eta)$ on Set which is generated by the adjunction.  Can we see a concrete example of:

1. $L(S)$, for $S \in Set$
2. $\mu : L \cdot L \rightarrow L$
3. $\eta : 1_{Set} \rightarrow L$

Does the adjunction also generate a comonad on Set?  If so, can we see concrete examples of the co-multiplication and co-unit?

I have a pet physical theory that states that the category of physical data for a system should admit a (co)monad structure and the theory itself is a factorization of the (co)monad.  I don't have any proof of the general theorem.  In this  case,  the category of the data for the theory is Set.  LieAlg is a theory of physics.  Set admits bimonads, and I am expecting the functor $L$ to admit a bimonad structure.

Comment: There's a completely general answer to this question in the theory of [Lawvere Theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) and closely related areas. Basically, the free algebraic whatever, $L(S)$, is the [term algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_algebra) over the set $S$ generated by the operations quotiented by the congruence generated by the axioms. $\eta$ sends an element to the "variable" labelled by that element. $\mu$ just replaces the "variables" labelled by terms with the terms themselves.

Comment: You may want to check out [Lyndon basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra#Lyndon_basis).

Comment: I would still like to see some concrete examples.

Comment: I'm confused about the comonadic aspect of the question. Are you asking whether $L$ itself also admits a comonad structure? Why would you expect that? That's a very special phenomenon, of which I don't know any examples outside of Hopf algebra theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $L(S)$ is the underlying set of the *free* Lie algebra over set $S$: 
   We take formal linear combinations of formal Lie brackets of elements of $S$, then we quotient out the Lie algebra identities.
2. Well, $LL(S)$ is then the free Lie algebra built on $L(S)$, we can express its elements by putting in parentheses in the formal expressions, e.g. with $a,b,c\in S$, the following formal expression is in $LL(S)$: 
   $[(2[a,b]-[a,c]),\ (3a)]\ $ as a simple Lie bracket of two elements of $L(S)$. 
   Then $\mu$ just opens up the parentheses.
3. Guess what, $\eta$ will send $a\in S\,$ to $\,a\in L(S)$.
4. Yes, by duality, every adjunction also determines a comonad on the other category. 
   Note that here the free functor $F:Set\to LieAlg\,$ is left adjoint to the underlying set functor $U:LieAlg\to Set$, and that we have $L=UF$. 
   Then the comonad structure will be induced on the functor $FU:LieAlg\to LieAlg$. 
   Based on this, you can describe its counit and comultiplication.

Note also, as Derek commented, this is a very general pattern, applicable to all kinds of algebraic structures defined by equations, and even beyond..

Comment: Thanks for the examples @Berci.  I was actually wondering if the adjunction generates a comonad on Set.

Comment: I doubt. How would it?